# Reading graphic buffer and switching shader

Tags: libgdx

I try to implement click detection of overlapping transparent textures on a sprite batch. Because I need to know which texture has been clicked. The idea is to draw each texture in a unique color, map the click coordinate to the screen, read the pixel at this position and map the pixel-color back to a texture.

Should I do it in that way? How can I read the graphic buffer? Do I have to switch the texture shader to paint the texture in one color?